# Decompose a real symmetric matrix by an upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

An introduction to optimization by Edwin K. P. Chong and Stanislaw H. 2ak. Page-32. The question is that how to prove the following statement.

If $Q$ is a real symmetric matrix, then there exists an upper triangle matrix $V$ with diagonal entries $\alpha_{ii}$ s.t.
$$
 V^TQV=\left(
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        \alpha_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \alpha_{22} & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & \alpha_{nn} 
      \end{array}
    \right)
$$

where
$$
V=\left(
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        \alpha_{11} & \alpha_{21} & \cdots & \alpha_{n1} \\
        0 & \alpha_{22} & \cdots & \alpha_{n2} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & \alpha_{nn} 
      \end{array}
    \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

What can make you confused here is that there's a mistake regarding your symbols. The entries on the diagonal line of V^TQV are not necessarily the same as the entries on the diagonal line of V.

Comment: These symbols should be right. I copied them from the textbook.